# Copying a slideshow

Tags: frontend, image, gallery

I want to copy my entire slideshow from my homepage, and replicate it on another page...

The page is http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/

and i need it on http://crystelleclothing.co.uk/trends/

Tried copying and pasting into a new CMS page, into the content box... but no such luck :/

Any ideas?

**CODE UPDATE**

I input

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.nav-box').click(function() {
    if (jQuery('#mobi-nav-content').is(":hidden"))
    {
    jQuery('#mobi-nav-content').slideDown("fast");
    } else {
    jQuery('#mobi-nav-content').slideUp("fast");
    }
    return false;
    });
}); 
 </script>
```

and

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery('.brand-list').flexslider({
        namespace: "brand-list-",
        animation: "slide",
        easing: "easeInQuart",
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        animationSpeed: 400,                        
        pauseOnHover: true,
        controlNav: false,
        itemWidth: 225,
        itemMargin: 0
      });
    });
 </script>
```

then when I go back in, my scripts change to

```
 <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.nav-box').click(function() {
    if (jQuery('#mobi-nav-content').is(":hidden"))
    {
    jQuery('#mobi-nav-content').slideDown("fast");
    } else {
    jQuery('#mobi-nav-content').slideUp("fast");
    }
    return false;
    });
}); 
 // ]]></script>
```

and

```
 <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery('.brand-list').flexslider({
        namespace: "brand-list-",
        animation: "slide",
        easing: "easeInQuart",
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        animationSpeed: 400,                        
        pauseOnHover: true,
        controlNav: false,
        itemWidth: 225,
        itemMargin: 0
      });
    });
 // ]]></script>
```

is it commenting them out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you copy/pasted the wrong code.

This is the code you need:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        easing: "swing",
        slideshow: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,
        start: function(slider) {
            slider.controlNav.removeClass(namespace + "active2").eq(slider.animatingTo).addClass(namespace + "active2"); 
        },
        controlNav:false
    });
});
```

The one you had is not being used on your homepage either. It is probably still there due to the template you are using.

Comment: perfect Dan... Cheers mate !

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead. In the cms page, go to design> Layout Update XML and add the reference to your js file there.

Comment: hmm...

so I should put these scripts into a JS file and refrence it? could I do it as a single file for the two JS?

Comment: yes put it into a js file and reference it. I guess you can combine both into 1 file.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your javascript files are included.

Comment: I believed so... although I am not sure if Magento comments out the files, I have updates above

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a template and load it on the CMS page like

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/trends.phtml"}}
```

This way, you will have good control over PHP and inline JavaScript.

As for JavaScript and CSS files that come with flexslider, place them under skin/frontend/... (js directory) and corresponding CSS directory. Subsequently, (as webgal mentioned above) reference these files in the design > Layout Update XML section of the CMS page.